# Select element or first matching parent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to apply an overlay to the element being hovered on if it matches certain criteria, or to the first parent that matches the criteria if it doesn't.

Given the following sample HTML and assuming I want to apply the overlay to any element with a class 'matches':

```
<div class='matches'>
   some Text <span>some more text</span>
</div>
```

I'd like it where if the user hovers on 'some text' the overlay is applied to the div and if they hover over 'some more text' the overlay is also applied to the div since that is the first parent with a class of 'matches'.

The only way I can think to do this would be to watch for a hover event on every single element which seems very inefficient. Is that okay to do, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This should work</strike>

```
$('.matches').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    // $(this) is .matches element
})
```

Edit - original was overly complex. `$(this)` should be the element you want.

Posting the asker's solution here to make it easier to find:

http://jsfiddle.net/swwh8/1/

```
$('.matches').hover(function(e) {
    $('.matches').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    e.stopPropagation();
}, function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().closest('.matches').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: I tried this and am having trouble getting it to work as I'd like. Looking at my example above, let's say the span tag also includes the matches class. In that case as a user hovere over the 'some text' I'd want the div highlighted. When they hovered over 'some more text' I'd like the highlighting to be removed from the div and applied to the span instead. When testing that, I never seem to get an event as I move into the span. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/swwh8/. If I understand what you want, that fiddle isn't quite right, but it's close. It works if you go from the outer element to the inner element, but not the other way around, because when you move from the inner element to the outer, mouseover on the outer element doesn't trigger, because technically, when you were hovering the inner element, you were also hovering the outer element.

Comment: I think you understand the problem, and pretty much nailed it. You're right that I also want to capture when it is leaving the child and moving back to the parent. I added a line to your sample and it worked perfectly (at least in this super simple scenario). For anyone else who needs the update you can get it here http://jsfiddle.net/swwh8/1/ Thanks!